# React frontend Admin panel ( Firebase Auth email/password ) & Mongodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, firebase

im buildig ReactJS Frontend Admin panel for my Nodejs project
it uses Firebase Auth and mongodb
my proble is whatever i do the Dashboard always blank after redirect succuess login
Files as following:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContextProvider } from './AuthContext';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import Login from './Login';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'; // Import Dashboard.js here
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} /> {/* Public route */}
          <Route
            path="/dashboard"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <Dashboard /> {/* Dashboard component here */}
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**and AuthContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  const login = (user) => {
    setCurrentUser(user);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setCurrentUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthContextProvider');
  }
  return context;
};
```

**and PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from './AuthContext'; // Import useAuth hook

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth(); // Use the useAuth hook to access currentUser

  return currentUser ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**and index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**and Login.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "./firebase-config"; // Import your Firebase app
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"; // Import from Firebase
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"; // Import for navigation
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext"; // Import AuthContext using useAuth

const Login = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { login } = useAuth(); // Use the useAuth hook to access setCurrentUser

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        e.target.email.value,
        e.target.password.value
      );

      // Set a success message
      setError("Login Successful!");

      // Update currentUser in AuthContext (assuming your AuthContext manages user state)
      login(userCredential.user);

      // Redirect to Dashboard after successful login
      navigate("/dashboard");
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message); // Set the error message in the state
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div id="root" className="min-h-100vh flex grow bg-slate-50 dark:bg-navy-900" x-cloak="true">
        <main className="grid w-full grow grid-cols-1 place-items-center">
          <div className="w-full max-w-[26rem] p-4 sm:px-5">
            <div className="text-center">
              <img className="mx-auto w-32" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
              <div className="mt-4">
                <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-slate-600 dark:text-navy-100">
                  Welcome Back
                </h2>
                <p className="text-slate-400 dark:text-navy-300">
                  Please sign in to continue
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={handleLogin} className="card mt-5 rounded-lg p-5 lg:p-7">
              <label className="block">
                <span>Username:</span>
                <span className="relative mt-1.5 flex">
                  <input className="form-input peer w-full rounded-lg border border-slate-300 bg-transparent px-3 py-2 pl-9 placeholder:text-slate-400/70 hover:z-10 hover:border-slate-400 focus:z-10 focus:border-primary dark:border-navy-450 dark:hover:border-navy-400 dark:focus:border-accent" placeholder="Enter Username" type="email" id="email" required/>
                  <span className="pointer-events-none absolute flex h-full w-10 items-center justify-center text-slate-400 peer-focus:text-primary dark:text-navy-300 dark:peer-focus:text-accent">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-5 w-5 transition-colors duration-200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                      <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="1.5" d="M3 8l7.89 5.26a2 2 0 002.22 0L21 8M5 19h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2z"/>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
              </label>
              <label className="mt-4 block">
                <span>Password:</span>
                <span className="relative mt-1.5 flex">
                  <input className="form-input peer w-full rounded-lg border border-slate-300 bg-transparent px-3 py-2 pl-9 placeholder:text-slate-400/70 hover:z-10 hover:border-slate-400 focus:z-10 focus:border-primary dark:border-navy-450 dark:hover:border-navy-400 dark:focus:border-accent" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password" id="password" required/>
                  <span className="pointer-events-none absolute flex h-full w-10 items-center justify-center text-slate-400 peer-focus:text-primary dark:text-navy-300 dark:peer-focus:text-accent">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-5 w-5 transition-colors duration-200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                      <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="1.5" d="M12 15v2m-6 4h12a2 2 0 002-2v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2zm10-10V7a4 4 0 00-8 0v4h8z"/>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
              </label>
              
    {error && (<div class="alert flex space-x-2 rounded-lg border border-error px-4 py-4 text-error">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7 4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zm-1-9a1 1 0 00-1 1v4a1 1 0 102 0V6a1 1 0 00-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
    </svg>
    <p>{error === 'Login Successful!' ? 'Success!' : error}</p>
    </div>)}

      <p className="error-message"></p>
                <button type="submit" className="btn mt-5 w-full bg-primary font-medium text-white hover:bg-primary-focus focus:bg-primary-focus active:bg-primary-focus/90 dark:bg-accent dark:hover:bg-accent-focus dark:focus:bg-accent-focus dark:active:bg-accent/90">Login</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>

      <div id="x-teleport-target"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**the package.json**

```
{
  "name": "admin-panel",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^10.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Finally the Dashboard.js component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from './AuthContext'; // Import useAuth hook

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth(); // Access currentUser from AuthContext
  const [error, setError] = useState(null); // State for error message

  // Fetch error data from your backend or state management solution (if applicable)
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchErrorData = async () => {
      try {
        // Replace with your actual error data fetching logic (e.g., API call)
        const response = await fetch('/api/dashboard/errors'); // Example API call
        const errorData = await response.json();
        setError(errorData?.message); // Update error state with fetched message
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching error data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchErrorData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="dashboard-container">
      <h1 className="dashboard-heading">Welcome, {currentUser.displayName || currentUser.email}!</h1>
      {error && (
        <div className="error-log alert alert-error">
          <svg className="h-5 w-5 mr-2" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.7-7.29a4 4 0 00-2.82-2.82L13.7 6.9l-1.41-1.41a4 4 0 00-2.82 2.82l-1.41 1.41L6.9 13.7a4 4 0 002.82 2.82L10 16.1l1.41 1.41a4 4 0 002.82-2.82l1.41-1.41z" clipRule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
          <p>{error}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      <p className="dashboard-message">You are now logged in to your dashboard.</p>

      {/* Additional dashboard content and features go here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

i almost tried everything without any success
also i browser consoel i got the following error :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'observeDomChanges' has already been declared (at ruleApplier.js:1:1)

but there is no ruleApplier.js in the project at all
and the docx for react and firebase have nothing about it :(
anyone faced such issue ?!!
any suggestion will be helpful at this point :D

Comment: Are you using Stands adblocker by any chance? if so, it is causing the issue https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/2837#issuecomment-1962884525